# Xdebug profiling shows different execution time than actual one

Tags: php, mysql, profiling, xdebug

I am profiling my website and when I use Xdebug profile
on one of my pages I got results that states:

`1977 different functions called in 3900 milliseconds (1 runs, 1977 shown)`

But the actual `execution time` measured at top and bottom of `index.php` file
states:

`20 seconds`

Where I am losing so much seconds ?

How to check what takes that time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that webpage I was profiling got a redirect. So the profiler showed time for the profiling page but my measurements in `index.php` showed time after redirect.